# Travis-ci build not working for iOS swift projects

Tags: swift, build, travis-ci, xcodebuild

I have the following lines of code in my .travis.yml file:

```
language: objective-c
xcode_workspace: Diffusion.xcworkspace
xcode_scheme: Diffusion
```

However my build continuously fails everytime. I have looked up other resources on the matter but for some reason it always fails. I have exhausted all these other options as well:

```
#option 1
language: objective-c
podfile: Podfile
script: xcodebuild -workspace Diffusion.xcworkspace -scheme Diffusion -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
```

The script tag works on my local machine.

```
#option 2
language: objective-c
podfile: Podfile
branches:
  only:
    - master
osx_image: xcode8.2
xcode_workspace: Diffusion.xcworkspace
xcode_scheme: Diffusion
xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator10.2
```

If I could get help on the matter, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

These are the current logs I get [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/196229744/log.txt)

Comment: It would certainly help if you showed the errors logged from a failed build.

Comment: @renemilk Sorry about that I added the logs to the description